# Replacing last occurrence of character group with Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I have strings like the following in my Oracle 11g table:

```
ABCDEF000xyz12345abcdefgh

GHIJK0000def67890abcdefgh
```

I.e., the strings begin with capital letters followed by a series of zeros, followed by three characters, digits and characters again.

How can I replace the `xyz12345abcdefgh` and `def67890abcdefgh` with a certain string using REGEXP_REPLACE in Oracle?

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions below? If yes, what is still blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to only select the records of the type you mentioned, consider using

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^([[:upper:]]+0+)[[:alpha:]]{3}\d+[[:alpha:]]+$', '\1NEW_STRING')
```

where

- `^` - a start of string
- `([[:upper:]]+0+)` - capturing group #1 matching:

  - `[[:upper:]]+` - 1 or more uppercase letters
  - `0+` - one or more `0` chars
- `[[:alpha:]]{3}`  - 3 alphabetic chars
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `[[:alpha:]]+` - 1 or more alphabetic chars
- `$` - end of string.

The `\1` in the replacement string is a *backreference* that inserts the value stored in the capturing group #1 buffer.

[image]

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/IRXB26217).

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_replace(column_name,'(.*)([0]{2,})(.*)','\1\2xxxx') from table_name;
```